# How to get an array of elements which have an attribute attr with value val

Tags: javascript, dom

Let say I've got a node `elem` containing child nodes with an attribute `attr`.
How can I get an array of all the child nodes such that the value of `attr` attribute is `val` **without jQuery**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sentence is a little unclear but you seem to want

```
element.querySelectorAll('[attr]')
```

and

```
element.querySelectorAll('[attr="val"]')
```

See [Element.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.querySelectorAll)

Note that this function returns a [nodelist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList). If you really need an array, you can do this :

```
var arr = [].slice.call(element.querySelectorAll('[attr="val"]'))
```

Comment: what difference is between `element.querySelector` and `element.querySelectorAll` ?

Comment: querySelector only returns the first matching element. It's mostly useful when you know there's only one match.